# Is it a bug to discard passed rest-props to a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm developing my wrapper over flexbox in react: https://github.com/aush/react-stack. I have a top level component that creates a container div and sets flex properties to it and also I map over it's children and set flex properties to them (I don't create additional wrapper divs for children, just set flex properties directly to them). And it's works flawlessly except one case.

My component, stripped down:

```
export default ({ someprops, style, children, ...rest }) => 
  <div style={{ ...style, ...flexContainerStyle }} {...rest}>
  {
    React.Children.map(children, (child, i) =>
      React.cloneElement(child, 
        { key: i, style: { ...child.props.style, ...flexItemStyle } }))
  }
  </div>;
```

Consider this simple example, when all children are just standard divs:

[codepen example 1](http://codepen.io/aush/pen/obQvjo)

```
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Horizontal>
      <div className="box1">1</div>
      <div className="box2">2</div>
      <Vertical>
        <div className="box3">3</div>
        <Horizontal grow={1}>
          <div className="box4" align={'end'}>4</div>
          <div className="box5" align={'end'}>5</div>
          <div className="box6" align={'end'}>6</div>
        </Horizontal>
      </Vertical>
    </Horizontal>,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
```

Now, let's say I have these two react components: `BuggedComponent` and `NotBuggedComponent` and put them as children:

[codepen example 2](http://codepen.io/aush/pen/zrMOBN)

```
  const BuggedComponent = ({ children }) => 
    <div className="box5">{children}</div>;
  const NotBuggedComponent = ({ children, ...rest }) => 
    <div className="box6" { ...rest }>{children}</div>;

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Horizontal>
      <div className="box1">1</div>
      <div className="box2">2</div>
      <Vertical>
        <div className="box3">3</div>
        <Horizontal grow={1}>
          <div className="box4" align={'end'}>4</div>
          <BuggedComponent align={'end'}>5</BuggedComponent>
          <NotBuggedComponent align={'end'}>6</NotBuggedComponent>
        </Horizontal>
      </Vertical>
    </Horizontal>,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
```

In this case, `box 5` doesn't have any properties besides ones `BuggedComponent` sets itself.

It appears that properties set to the 'bugged' component are lost, obviously, because this component, essentially, discards rest-properties. For me it's a clear bug, not even just a bad practice. But I've taken a look at some github repos and I see that this quite a common practice and I cannot find any articles/guides which state this issue and point it as a bad practice.

The only argument for not passing rest that I have is that it's not clear, *where* rest-props should be passed. But since a react component can has only one root, it's rather natural that rest-props should be passed to it.

So, the question is: is it really, unfortunatelly very common, bad practice, or there is some explanation to why discarding rest-properties is the right way to develop react components?

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to how much control over own child components does the dev intends to hand out to the consumers. In this case the `BuggedComponent` is generating a child div and it makes sense for it to pass on the rest properties to it. However, if the child would have been a more complex control where allowing arbitrary attributes does not make sense, there won't be a need for passing them down. Yours is a very specific case where you need absolute control over what class the child control has, but this may not be true in a general scenario. A good example is the very popular [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com) library, if you look at any complex control, it minutely controls the allowed props and almost never passes them down. It could make keeping inner-markup change-proof very difficult, apart from the simplest of cases.